# Xcode displays error when building Mac app for release

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm writing an application for OS X using core data. It's no problem to build and run it for debugging but when I switch to release or try to archive it, it throws the error

```
'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Headers/NSFetchRequestExpression.h:15:39: Attempting to use the forward class 'NSExpression' as superclass of 'NSFetchRequestExpression'
```

When I delete all fetch request from the code, it works fine.
Does anybody know what problem this could be? Thank you.

Here are the header:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "EFMainController.h"

@interface EF_AppDelegate : NSObject
{
    IBOutlet NSMenu *statusMenu;
    NSStatusItem *statusItem;
    NSWindow *window;

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
    EFMainController *mainController;
    NSTabView *tabView;
    IBOutlet NSImageView *dockTileView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet EFMainController *mainController;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTabView *tabView;

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator;
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel;
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext;
- (IBAction)saveAction:sender;

@end
```

and

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface EFMainController : NSObject  {
    /* some variables */
}

/* some properties and actions */
@end
```

The stuff where I put the comments has nothing to do with core data

Comment: Something is wrong in one of your files that uses CoreData, which is causing `NSFetchRequestExpression` to be imported incorrectly. Can you post the code for the header(s)/implementation(s) that use CoreData? Potentially where you are using `@class` (as you could have a lot of source code). This is tricky to debug without any code, but it boils down to incorrect importing/incorrect forward declarations using the `@class` directive.

Comment: try to insert this line: `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` before the CoreData import and link to Foundation framework

Comment: Where do I link to Foundation framework?

Comment: OK, I think you mean "Link Binary With Libraries" under the "Build Phases" tab. I did that but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I have a program where I experience the same Problem and so far I could not really solve it but I was able to somewhat build it for release. So I guess this is not a real/full answer but for me it worked to use Product > Build For > Archiving.